# Undefined variable when attempting to store messages PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a variable called `$message` which outputs the message contents when an action is performed to give the user some feedback however I keep getting an `undefined variable` error from PHP.

It's really weird because sometimes it works fine and other times it just returns the error message. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Just to confirm, this is a variable which is purely for storing messages. This isn't something which is "POSTED' from a form. Its generated within the PHP file itself.

An example of its usage:

```
<?php

session_start();

include "../includes/db_conx.php";

try
{
   $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

   $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

   $username = $_SESSION['username'];

   $sql = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT username, user_record_id FROM login_details
    WHERE username = :username");

   $sql->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   $sql->execute();
   $user_record_id = $sql->fetchColumn(1);

   $proposal = $_POST['proposal_id'];

   $insertRec = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO student_saved (proposal_id, user_record_id) VALUES (:proposal, :user_record_id)");

   $insertRec->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $insertRec->bindParam(':proposal', $proposal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $insertRec->execute();

   $message = "<p class='text-success'> Proposal Added To Your Favourites <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/></p>";
}

catch(Exception $e)
{
    if( $e->getCode() == 23000)
    {
        $message = 'This proposal has already been saved to your favourites';
    }
    else
    {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

die($message);
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this piece of code always or sometimes giving you this error.

Comment: sometimes. I ran it twice today and successfully got the message back but then when i ran it a third time it gave me an error and continued to do so after that

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not break this code into different parts so you can test each portion by itself? Perhaps a class that runs this script in different parts? It may help narrow down where things are going wrong